# Use df name as file name when exporting in R

Tags: r

I've created a function that helps me with extracting processed datasets to XLS saving them in a defined path and with a specified format always. However, I'd like to automate completely the name of the file by using, by default, the name of the df. What I have so far is the below function:

```
ExportFile <- function(y) {
  write_xlsx(
    y,
    str_replace_all(paste("C:/MyPath/",
                          format(today(),"%Y%m%d"),
                          "_",
                          MyDataFrame,
                          ".xlsx"),
                    pattern=" ", repl="")
  )
}
```

The idea is that the "MyDataFrame" text can be the same that I use for the expression (`ExportFile(MyDataFrame)`).

As an extra point, would be amazing if someone can tell me how to do the below:

- If I write `ExportFile(MyDataFrame)` it will create a file called
  *20191002_MyDataFrame.xlsx*.
- But if I write `ExportFile(MyDataFrame,test)` it will create a file called
  *20191002_test.xlsx*.

Anyone has the solution for, at least, the 1st one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substitute()` to get the symbol of the variable passed to a function. If we make the name a default parameter that uses the name of the variable by default, you can achieve what you are after. So you might do something like this

```
ExportFile <- function(y, data_name=deparse(substitute(y))) {
  fn <- paste("C:/MyPath/",
                          format(today(),"%Y%m%d"),
                          "_",
                          data_name,
                          ".xlsx")
  write_xlsx(
    y,
    str_replace_all(fn, pattern=" ", repl="")
  )
}
```

With a more repoducible example for testing

```
ExportFileName <- function(y, data_name=deparse(substitute(y))) {
  paste0("C:/MyPath/",
    format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"),
    "_",
    gsub(" ","",data_name),
    ".xlsx")
}
ExportFileName(iris)
# [1] "C:/MyPath/20191002_iris.xlsx"
ExportFileName(iris, "flowers")
# [1] "C:/MyPath/20191002_flowers.xlsx"
```

Comment: That was quick :)
However, in the 2nd code that you pasted you did not add the "writeXLS" part. I've added this before the paste0 and it worked perfectly. Thanks!